# SharePoint 2010 OWA Error when opening a Word Document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, owa

We are having an issue for OWA when opening a word document, but it affect few documents only. Here is the error:

[image]

I have followed [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2014/04/22/owa-2010-cannot-open-this-document-for-viewing-because-of-an-unexpected-error.aspx).

And I deleted the Cache but it did not resolve the issue. I did enable verbose logging to re-produce the issue and here is the log:

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Starting correlation.   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://serversp05ap.company.local:32843/b05c449f1b454bb4a30793d522efc18e/Conversion.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/IConvertingService/GetCachedItem' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:7afb0d7b-33b8-4cb2-8af5-c2d95cc534eb'  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Starting correlation. Transfer from f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb    9f2cac88-ac40-4e62-861a-b379bead3336
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=ExecuteWcfServerOperation  9f2cac88-ac40-4e62-861a-b379bead3336
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  Office Web Apps                 Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Starting correlation.   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  Office Web Apps                 Office Web Apps Configuration   bbw9    Verbose Trying to get setting APPLICATIONMANAGERISENABLED   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     9mk6    Medium  GetCachedItem() [Doc: Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, Item docdata.xml, Format: Silverlight, ConvCalls: 0, DataCalls: 1   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     c7l7    Medium  GetCachedItem() result: InProgress for item docdata.xml, document Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  Office Web Apps                 Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.840120741602634   9f2cac88-ac40-4e62-861a-b379bead3336
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. Transfer to f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb    9f2cac88-ac40-4e62-861a-b379bead3336
04/23/2015 09:57:10.33  w3wp.exe (serverSP05AP:0x2414)              0x6DD0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Starting correlation. Transfer from 29364b48-bc56-4f02-bf59-bbd22e825eb5    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://mysite.company.local:80/subsite/docs/hrebsint/_vti_bin/docdatahandler.ashx?d=Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m&z=706E2642-E37D-4BE4-98F1-0FE07F8CF2C75&type=sl&ui=en-US)    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           SQM                             97qu    Verbose SQM: Datapoint id 6693 marked as Increment datapoint.   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  User=Domain\JohnDoe f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Logging Correlation Data        9gc5    Verbose Thread change; resetting trace level override to 0; resetting correlation to f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb 29364b48-bc56-4f02-bf59-bbd22e825eb5  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Web Apps Configuration   bbw9    Verbose Trying to get setting WORDVIEWERISENABLED   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Web Apps Configuration   bbx0    Verbose Tried to obtain setting WORDVIEWERISENABLED but it does not exist in the list of known settings for this environment.   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/subsite/docs  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Web Apps Globalization   cg8m    Verbose Created regional settings with ui = 1033 and data = 1033.   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     9rgn    Verbose DocDataHandler request: doc=Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, tech=Silverlight  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     vjyu    Medium  Librarian.BeginGetItem(Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, Silverlight, docdata.xml)  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     b4vj    Verbose DocumentInfoCache.GetDocumentCacheItem: docId=d=Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m&z=706E2642-E37D-4BE4-98F1-0FE07F8CF2C75, outputFormat=_v00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000201, hashcode=1450402086  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     b4vk    Verbose DocumentInfoCache.GetDocumentCacheItem: Item found  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     vkay    Medium  ViewStore.TryGetItemFromBackend(Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, Silverlight, docdata.xml, http://serversp05ap:32843/b05c449f1b454bb4a30793d522efc18e/Conversion.svc)  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     fx1t    Verbose OpenChannel for http://serversp05ap:32843/b05c449f1b454bb4a30793d522efc18e/Conversion.svc took 0.1662 ms    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     wydn    Verbose ConvertingServiceProxy created to uri=http://serversp05ap:32843/b05c449f1b454bb4a30793d522efc18e/Conversion.svc f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     b4vg    Medium  Requesting cached item docdata.xml from http://serversp05ap:32843/b05c449f1b454bb4a30793d522efc18e/Conversion.svc; DocId: Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://serversp05ap:32843/b05c449f1b454bb4a30793d522efc18e/Conversion.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Framework.Remoting.IConvertingService' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/IConvertingService/GetCachedItem' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:7afb0d7b-33b8-4cb2-8af5-c2d95cc534eb'    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.34  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     fx1s    Verbose TryGetItemFromBackend took 0.4717 ms    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x3E28  Office Web Apps                 Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Starting correlation.   f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x3E28  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     vkbf    Medium  ViewStore.OnReceivedItemFromBackend(Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, Silverlight, docdata.xml) - state InProgress  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x3E28  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     vkaw    Medium  ViewStore.SetCompleted(Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, Silverlight, docdata.xml) - status = InProgress    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x3E28  Office Web Apps                 Office Viewing Architecture     vjzo    Medium  Librarian.SetCompleted(Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m, Silverlight, docdata.xml) - status = InProgress    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x3E28  Office Web Apps                 Word Web App Viewer             bhl2    Verbose DocDataHandler Response is being sent.  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x3E28  Office Web Apps                 Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        9gc5    Verbose Thread change; resetting trace level override to 0; resetting correlation to f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb 29364b48-bc56-4f02-bf59-bbd22e825eb5  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         cn4g    Verbose Trace level override is turned off. f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://mysite.company.local:80/subsite/docs/hrebsint/_vti_bin/docdatahandler.ashx?d=Fc24bb5cf47554a14b0509fd67859a26ema89d59704d14443f824f9fa001a81e56m706e2642e37d4be498f10fe07f8cf2c7m&z=706E2642-E37D-4BE4-98F1-0FE07F8CF2C75&type=sl&ui=en-US)). Execution Time=14.8252082317725  f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
04/23/2015 09:57:10.35  w3wp.exe (serverSP02W:0x8A78)               0x4188  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. Transfer to 29364b48-bc56-4f02-bf59-bbd22e825eb5    f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb
```

Comment: None of those state the error associated with the correlation ID.. How many servers are in your farm and how many host OWA?

Comment: We have 3 servers that is running the word view services. in total we have 6 servers. I obtained the log by running PS Cmdlet: Merge-SPLogFile -Path C:\Error.log -Correlation "f518e19f-674e-4142-b62f-ed030568b4eb"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for [SharePoint 2010 OWA Error](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21739.sharepoint-2010-word-web-app-cannot-open-this-document-for-viewing-because-of-an-unexpected-error.aspx) when opening a Word Document issue.